# Breve rest symbol using Musixtex with amsmath package

Tags: amsmath, musixtex

It is needed to implement a Breve rest symbol using Musixtex with amsmath package (as we need to use math). The basic code is as follow:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{spanish}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{musixtex} 

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{tabularx} %Tabla con ajuste de ancho
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{multirow,booktabs,setspace,caption}

\xdefinecolor{gray-undar}{RGB}{52,52,52}%0-0-100
\xdefinecolor{red-undar}{RGB}{179,35,79}%341-80-70 

\begin{document} 

\begin{center}
\begin{table}[H]
\caption{Notas con sus equivalentes silencios}
\label{tab:NotasConSilencios}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[transform shape,scale=0.6]{
\centering\centering\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{2.1}
\begin{tabular}{!{\color{red-undar}\vrule}m{4.9cm}!{\color{red-undar}\vrule}m{2.5cm}!{\color{red-undar}\vrule}m{3.7cm}!{\color{red-undar}\vrule}m{3.9cm}!{\color{red-undar}\vrule}m{3.5cm}!{\color{red-undar}\vrule}}
\arrayrulecolor{red-undar}\hline  
\centering\bfseries\sffamily Name & \centering\bfseries\sffamily Note & \centering\bfseries\sffamily Rest & \centering\bfseries\sffamily Equivalents & \\
\hline
Breve (Double Whole Note) & \begin{music}
    \nostartrule
    \setclefsymbol1{\empty}
    \setlines{1}{0}
    \let\breve=\relax        
    \startextract
    \hskip0.1\elemskip
    \NOtes\breve{c}\zcn{b}{\hspace*{-0.3cm}ó}\qsk\wqq{c}\en
    \zendextract
\end{music} & \begin{music}
    \nostartrule
    \setclefsymbol1{\empty}
    \vskip4.1\elemskip
    \startextract
    \hskip0.1\elemskip
    \NOTEs\hsk\PAuse\en
    \zendextract
\end{music} & Two Whole Notes & \begin{music}
    \nostartrule
    \setclefsymbol1{\empty}
    \setlines{1}{0}        
    \startextract
    \hskip0.1\elemskip
    \NOtes\wh{c}\hqsk\wh{c}\en
    \zendextract
\end{music} \\
\hline
\end{tabular}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{table}
\end{center}
 
\end{document}
```

The current output is as follow:
[image: current]

The desired output is as follow:

[image: desired]

Note: We need to use both packages at the same time: musixtex and amsmath

Comment: Don't forget to translate the content of the table into Spanish …

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most simple way is to substitute `\breve{c}`
by

```
\zbreve{c}\sk
```

because `\zbreve` is no command in `amsmath`.
Besides, please improve your music code by ending the lines with `%`. For all lines ending with `}` or a number this is necessary. And avoid spaces at the end of a line.

Comment: Another possibility is to define an alias like breveA:                                                         \usepackage{musixtex} 
\let\breveA=\breve